# Does Apache HttpClient have an equivalent to OkHttp newBuilder?

Tags: kotlin, apache-httpclient-4.x

To create an Apache HttpClient I use the HttpClientBuilder or HttpClients class such as in the following example (Kotlin):

```
val client = HttpClients.custom()
    .setSSLContext(sslContext)
    .build()
```

With OkHttp I would be able to create "copies" (?) of this client and modify them e.g. like this:

```
val newClient = client.newBuilder()
    .setRoutePlanner(routePlanner)
    .build()
```

Is there an equivalent for Apache HttpClients? Or put differently: How can I modify (or create a modified copy of) an existing HttpClient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not. Generally one should never to re-configure `HttpClient`. `HttpClient` should be created once in a life span of a client endpoint.

One should use `HttpContext` to customize and configure all aspects of request execution and response processing.